# iphone text message colours

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am working on a messaging application for iphone , can anyone tell me how to achieve the green color for the messages received like in the image shown below[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are custom views with custom images. Easiest way is probably to draw the bubble in the smallest way possible and use [-[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth%3atopCapHeight%3a) to create a stretchable image and draw that in your custom view as background.

Answer (score 0):

I think that green color bubble is an Image.